# Один класс с модификатором public в классе

Tags: java, классы, дизайн-языка

Мы можем создать в одном файле несколько классов, но только один из них может быть с модификатором public, почему?

Comment: А как назвать файл с кучей разных классов? Чтобы не иметь мешанину в проекте, принято создавать 1 публичный класс на файл

Comment: @tym32167, ну в других языках иногда бывают исключения. Особенно, в случае сгенерированного кода удобно генерировать один файл, а не кучу.

Comment: @Qwertiy много таких примеров? Я пользуюсь генераторами типа dagger, там также 1 класс на файл. Когда с T4 немного работал - тоже было удобно 1 класс на файл. Небольшие файлы тупо читать удобней, чем искать их в куче текста большого файла. Конечно, если сгенерированные классы читать не нужно - тогда пусть в куче лежат (типа всякие автогенерированные прокси классы для wcf или классы для antlr- но я честно даже про них не помню, один там файл или несколько)

Comment: @tym32167, тайпскрипт по сваггеру - один файл. Но там не классы, а типы. И вроде, там всего 2 или 3 корневых типа, а остальное внутри. Несколько связанных react-компонентов было удобно в один файл класть - раньше они были классовыми, так что несколько классов. Wfc использовал, но не помню, что там со сгенерированными файлами. Antlr тоже использовал - вроде бы там несколько файлов, но точно не помню; в любом случае, там конечный автомат для разбора, а ему много классов не надо. Возможно, я бы положил класс итератора в одном файле с классом коллекции (но есть подозрение, что он будет вложенным).

Comment: @Qwertiy ну так это все более-менее вписывается в то, что вы ше писал. Даже для реакт компонентов - ты можешь несколько связанных в файле держать, а ты экспортишь один только из них, онстальные - вспомогательные.

Comment: @tym32167, неа, я экспортирую все. Они не вспомогательные.

Comment: @Qwertiy и не получается мешанины кода? Я прост пробовал, потом рефачить пришлось, а то черт ногу сломит в такой лапше

Comment: @tym32167, от ситуации зависит. Если там 3 однотипных компонента из нескольких строк, то нормально лежат.

Answer (score 0):

Основная причина для такого ограничения, которое тянется ещё со времени разработки предшественника Java - [языка Oak](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue055-Once-Upon-an-Oak-....html):

> In section 1, we read: "Although each Oak compilation unit can contain multiple classes or interfaces, at most one class or interface per compilation unit can be public".
>
> In the sidebar it explains why: "This restriction is not yet enforced by the compiler, although it's necessary for efficient package importation"
>
> It's pretty obvious - like most things are once you know the design reasons - the compiler would have to make an additional pass through all the compilation units (.java files) to figure out what classes were where, and that would make the compilation even slower.

То есть, такой подход позволяет ускорить компиляцию, иначе компилятору понадобился бы дополнительный проход, чтобы определить, какой класс содержится в каком файле исходного кода.

Кроме того, строгая стандартизированная организация кодовой базы в проектах, содержащих сотни и тысячи файлов с классами, позволяет улучшить стиль и читаемость кода.

---

Однако следует заметить, что в одном `.java` файле может быть объявлено несколько классов с модификатором `public` в том же файле (с учётом вложенных и статических классов), но только один публичный класс может быть объявлен на *верхнем уровне* (top level class):

```java
public class Top {
    public class Inner {}
    public static class NestedStatic {}
}
```

Comment: Что-то не то про компиляцию. При компиляции internal-классы тоже придётся доставать. А то, что в файле не может быть более одного public-класса не означает, что там есть хоть один, так что файл читать всё равно придётся.